Jquery stick element image replacement

Trying to create these kind of screen transitions - a sticky image, that then gets replaced with a similar version but on a different theme colour.
What scroll formula/value is being used to control the height of the white-holder element so that it replaces the dark mode with the light.
I've tried to increase the height of the container to test this component.
https://jsfiddle.net/5fprngcL/14/


  $( document ).ready(function() {

    console.log("ready")
var myElement = $(".white-mode-holder");

function setHeight(yPos, el) {
  el.style.height = `${yPos}vh`;
}

$(document).scroll(function(e){
  
  console.log("e", e)
  
  let h = $("body").offset().top;
  console.log("h", h)
  
  setHeight(h*2, myElement[0])
  
});


  });
html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Manrope, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 2000px;
}

img {
    overflow-clip-margin: content-box;
    overflow: clip;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}



.dark-and-light-mode-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.dark-and-light-mode-sticky {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.dark-mode-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.white-mode-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.white-mode-holder{
    will-change: width, height;
    height: 0vh;
}


.center-iphone {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}



.dark-mode-hand-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 80px 0 0;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}



.dark-mode-hand {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}


.dark-mode-app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
}



.dark-mode-app-holder {
    padding: 2.6% 26% 26.2% 16%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div class="dark-and-light-mode-container">
    <div class="dark-and-light-mode-sticky">
      <div class="dark-mode-holder">
        <div class="center-iphone">
          <div class="dark-mode-hand-holder"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp" loading="eager" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 300px, 400px" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-800.webp 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp 848w" alt="" class="dark-mode-hand">
            <div class="dark-mode-app-holder"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b576894fd22717696b9ead_Dark%20Mode.webp" loading="eager" alt="" sizes="232px" srcset="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b576894fd22717696b9ead_Dark%20Mode-p-500.webp 500w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b576894fd22717696b9ead_Dark%20Mode-p-800.webp 800w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b576894fd22717696b9ead_Dark%20Mode.webp 1035w" class="dark-mode-app"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="white-mode-holder" style="will-change: width, height; height: 0vh;">
        <div class="center-iphone">
          <div class="dark-mode-hand-holder"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp" loading="eager" sizes="(max-width: 479px) 300px, 400px" srcset="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-800.webp 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp 848w" alt="" class="dark-mode-hand">
            <div class="dark-mode-app-holder"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b57689b7dd5c5baa9e0780_Light%20Mode.webp" loading="eager" alt="" sizes="232px" srcset="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b57689b7dd5c5baa9e0780_Light%20Mode-p-500.webp 500w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b57689b7dd5c5baa9e0780_Light%20Mode-p-800.webp 800w, https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b57689b7dd5c5baa9e0780_Light%20Mode.webp 1036w" class="dark-mode-app"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>



latest jsfiddle 11th Sep - using clip paths
https://jsfiddle.net/jdqgewfh/

clip-path inset animation  -> https://emilkowal.ski/ui/the-magic-of-clip-path

That is a good idea. The example I was looking at adjusts the height - so I guess in a similar way - either way its getting the logic and formula right to adjust either clip-path or height

It's def a clip-path animation. My thought was the stacking is the key. Almost all the elements are likely positioned absolute but the two app elements would be on top z-index, maybe an intersection observer to observe the background animations top colliding with the bottom of the app-card along with the clip-path would do it.

This is the reference site https://az-black.webflow.io/#download

You can do this by setting up your cards positions to stack on top of each other. The top card would be initially set to absolute so the scroll can control it. Set the hands position to sticky so it sticks to its top position. The bottom card set to fixed with a display of none. Then set up a scroll event on the window and track the parent element, top card and hand image elements positions relative to each other and the window, you can then calculate the percentage of the cards scroll and change a clipPath when the parent containers bottom is with in the cards top and bottom bounds.

el.style.clipPath: inset('${percentage}, 0, 0, 0') => Calculate the
difference between the top cards top position and the cards
parent containers bottom positions during scroll, then divide
this by the top cards height and multiply by 100. This will
give you the percentage of the inset for the clip-path
to use on the top card.

You will need to track the scrolling direction as well and affect the clipPath accordingly.
NOTE ON EDIT: I edited the snippet to reflect the images you used in your snippet.
See further comments in the snippet and let me know if anything is not clear.


// get the container element using ID
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
// get the top layer card with higher z-index
// this would be the element with the contrasting background
// of the scrolling container it is a child of
const topCard = document.querySelector('#top-card');
// get the hand element which will sit on top of both card elements
const hand = document.querySelector('#hand');

// get the bottom element
const bottomCard = document.querySelector('#bottom-card');

// set a variable to track scroll direction
let lastScrollTop = 0;
// callback method used to track scroll on window
const observeElementsScroll = e => {
  // variable to track windows scroll point for direction of scroll
  let dirOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  // added an element for the hand image
  // getBoundingClientRect for card and hand elements
  const handRect = hand.getBoundingClientRect();
  const contRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  const topCardRect = topCard.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // if your topcardRect.top <= 0, then we set bottomCards display to block
  // we set the topCards and hand images position to fixed 
  if (topCardRect.top <= 0) {
    bottomCard.style.display = 'block';
    topCard.style.position = 'fixed';
    hand.style.position = 'fixed';
  }
  // if containers top is greater than 0 set the bottomCard back 
  // to display of none and topCards position back to absolute so 
  // it can scroll and set the hand card to sticky
  if (contRect.top >= 0) {
    bottomCard.style.display = 'none';
    topCard.style.position = 'absolute';
    hand.style.position = 'sticky';
  }

  // get the top cards top and bottom bounds within the Document
  // if containers bottom is less than or equal to topCards bottom
  // AND containers bottom is greater than or equal to topCards top
  if (
    contRect.bottom <= topCardRect.bottom &&
    contRect.bottom >= topCardRect.top
  ) {
    // define our percentage -> take the difference of topCards.top
    // and subtract it with containers.bottom and convert to postive using Math.abs()
    // divide that by the height of the topCard and then mulitple by 100 = percentage

    // detect scroll direction and alter clipPaths first inset property
    // using percentage. Math.abs returns a whole number if number is negative.
    // Calculate the difference between topCards top and containers bottom positions 
    // during scroll, then divide this by the topCards height and multiply by 100
    if (dirOffset - lastScrollTop > 0) { // scrolling up
      topCard.style.clipPath = `inset(${Math.abs(topCardRect.top - contRect.bottom) / topCardRect.height * 100}% 0 100% 0)`;
    } else if (dirOffset - lastScrollTop < 0) { // scrolling down
      topCard.style.clipPath = `inset(${Math.abs(topCardRect.top - contRect.bottom) / topCardRect.height * 100}% 0 100% 0)`;
    }
    // added else if conditionals for when the parent containers bottom is out
    // of the bounds of the cards, this sets the clip-paths inset to static values 
    // and removes glitchy behavior if the scroll is moving fast with mouse wheel
  }else if(contRect.bottom < topCardRect.top) {
    topCard.style.clipPath = `inset(0% 0% 100% 0%)`;  
  }else if(contRect.bottom > topCardRect.bottom){
    topCard.style.clipPath = `inset(100% 0% 100% 0%)`;
  }

  // redefine the scrollTop for directional reference
  lastScrollTop = dirOffset;
}

// event listener for window scroll
addEventListener('scroll', observeElementsScroll)
body {
  height: 500vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#parent {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: relative;
}

#heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.cards {
  top: 14px;
  width: 290px;
}

.cards img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

#container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

#hand {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#top-card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 80px;
  clip-path: inset(100% 0% 100% 0%);
}

#bottom-card {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 80px;
  display: none;
}
<h2 id="heading">Scroll Down</h2>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="hand">
      <img src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-500.webp">
    </div>
    <div id="top-card" class="cards"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b57689b7dd5c5baa9e0780_Light%20Mode.webp">
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-card" class="cards"><img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b576894fd22717696b9ead_Dark%20Mode.webp">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




The example isnt showing any text?

I just put the lorem ipsum text in as an example, not sure what you mean.

@TheOldCounty I added the photos you are using in your example and tweaked the code a bit. The important part is the clip-path and calculation within the scroll event handler.

The contents of the image isnt there until you get to that scroll edge, and then when it transitions to the white version, there is a streak behind it. Why use a clip path over a height change - thats what the reference is doing instead

The contents of the image isnt there until you get to that scroll edge I fixed that. when it transitions to the white version, there is a streak behind it. - I do not see that in the snippet in Firefox. Why use a clip path over a height change - thats what the reference is doing instead Not sure what you mean, Are you referring to the example animation using a height change?

When it changes to the white version - should also have a white themed contents - yeah the reference changes height - https://az-black.webflow.io/#download

I see the animation in the example is smoother in nature and does indeed animate the height in vh units. Not sure how they are achieving that. I am going to leave this answer up in case it helps others looking for similar behavior, unless you would like me to remove. Best of luck.

@TheOldCounty you can def do this with GSAP. Look up scrollTrigger() in a .to() function set your top card holder as the trigger element, set height: 0 within the object as the height to animate to, use the top card as the trigger (scrubber), set your start top 0 and end as window.innerHeight and top, pin the top card and set scrub to true.

0
This is the latest version I have for this - but the codesandbox seems broken
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/plfszv

Here is a fiddle from your first post... maybe you can make it work in your project best of luck... https://jsfiddle.net/8c6tymg3/

This is the latest version I have for this - but the codesandbox seems broken
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/plfszv
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
//import "./style.css";
import { isMobile } from "react-device-detect";
import MobileViewCom from "./mobileView.js";

const Download = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("mainDivPositionget");
    let mainPositionSet = document.getElementById("stickyImagePositin");
    let shadowInTexts = document.getElementById("shadowInTexts");

    let topPosition = 0;
    let element = scrollableDiv;

    // Accumulate the offsetTop up the chain
    while (element) {
      topPosition += element.offsetTop;
      element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    console.log("Position from top:", topPosition);

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
      let makeScrollInImage;
      let offset = window.pageYOffset;
      console.log(offset);

      if (isMobile) {
        if (offset > topPosition) {
          mainPositionSet?.classList.add("stickyForMObile");
          makeScrollInImage = offset - (topPosition + 50);
        }
      } else {
        if (offset > topPosition + 250) {
          mainPositionSet?.classList.add("sticky");
          makeScrollInImage = offset - (topPosition + 50);
          // bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor;
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section id="download" className="section">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="effortlessly-integration-container">
          <div className="center-title">
            <div className="title-holder">
              <div className="fade-in-move-on-scroll">
                <h1 className="title">Start using Black now</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="fade-in-move-on-scroll">
                <div className="experience-paragraph-holder">
                  <p>
                    Start your free trial now and see how easy it is to track,
                    manage, and optimize your time.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="download-badge-holder">
            <div className="download-badge-container">
              <a
                href="http://applestore.com"
                target="_blank"
                className="download-badge-button w-inline-block"
              >
                <img
                  src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b55c334fd227405569f74b_App%20Store%20badge.svg"
                  loading="lazy"
                  alt=""
                  className="download-badge-image"
                />
              </a>
              <a
                href="http://googleplay.com"
                target="_blank"
                className="download-badge-button w-inline-block"
              >
                <img
                  src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b55c347e2c7082fffff214_Mobile%20App%20Store%20Badge.svg"
                  loading="lazy"
                  alt=""
                  className="download-badge-image"
                />
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[230vh] relative">
        <div className="w-full h-full absolute top-0 left-0 bottom-0 right-0">
          <div className="w-full h-[42%] bg-black"></div>
          <div className="w-full h-[60%] bg-white"></div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 grid justify-center"
          id="stickyImagePositin"
        >
          <div className=" translate-y-[-5px] relative">
            <div className="" id="getImageBackgroundCOlorName">
              <img
                src="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp"
                loading="eager"
                sizes="(max-width: 479px) 300px, 400px"
                srcSet="https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-500.webp 500w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand-p-800.webp 800w, https://assets.website-files.com/63aee5793ca698452efe7f60/63b5761b8fb633b42f3ad6c4_Iphone%20In%20Hand.webp 848w"
                alt=""
                className="dark-mode-hand"
              />
              <div className="dark-mode-app-holder overflow-hidden">
                <MobileViewCom />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Download;

